# I want to play a live stream on Unity after extracting the video from the m3u file

Tags: unity-game-engine, http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

I am trying to play an **m3u** file on Unity
My problem is when I extract a valid **.ts** link for download
As you know, **TS videos are not supported on Unity**
What is the solution in your opinion to play the ts files extracted from the m3u file?

This is the link for the live broadcast:

```
https://admdn5.cdn.mangomolo.com/drama/smil:drama.stream.smil/playlist.m3u8
```

What do you think is the solution, thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: You might just have to convert the file yourself :/

Comment: Thank you, the problem has already been resolved

Comment: If you solved the problem why not answer your own question so others can learn the solution too :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did not think of it, I will try it now

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Well I will do as you say, Sorry, I'm new to stack over flow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution after a long search Loading ts files and converting them to a readable file on Unity is difficult But the [UMP](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ump-win-mac-linux-webgl-49625) package helped me to read this format That's why I'm using it right now

**Note** : after downloading and trying the package it will not work, don't lose hope and try again inside a GameObjectsExample Scane